# Spring Multipart File upload under Pojo

Tags: spring-mvc, swagger-2.0, spring-restcontroller

Hi All I need help for `Multi-Part File Upload under the POJO class`. I'm using Swagger Image for Uploading the  List File's. When I run my code it show the request pattern as `JSON` instead of File Button

Class POJO :-

```
public class User {

    static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "The database generated user, token and session mapping ID.")
    private Long id;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "user name")
    private String username;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "User password")
    private String password;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Indicates whether the user is enabled or disabled. A disabled user cannot be authenticated.")
    private boolean enabled;

    @ApiModelProperty(notes = "Multiple file for user.", dataType = "java.io.File", required = true)
    private List<MultipartFile> multipartFiles;


}
```

Rest-Controller :-

```
@ApiOperation(value = "Authenticated User Login", response = User.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
@ApiResponses(value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Success", response = User.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 401, message = "Unauthorized"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Forbidden"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Not Found"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Failure")})
public ResponseEntity<User> fileUpload(@RequestBody User user) { return new ResponseEntity(user, HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

SwaggerConfig :-

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {

        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select().apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
                .paths(PathSelectors.any()).build().apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder().title("Authentication API").description("")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("https://www.example.com/api")
                .contact(new Contact("Developers", "https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/", ""))
                .license("Open Source")
                .licenseUrl("\"https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0")
                .version("1.0.0")
                .build();

    }

}
```

Swagger Show :-

```
{
  "enabled": false,
  "id": 0,
  "multipartFiles": {
    "absolute": true,
    "absolutePath": "string",
    "canonicalPath": "string",
    "directory": true,
    "executable": true,
    "file": true,
    "freeSpace": 0,
    "hidden": true,
    "lastModified": 0,
    "name": "string",
    "parent": "string",
    "path": "string",
    "readable": true,
    "totalSpace": 0,
    "usableSpace": 0,
    "writable": true
  },
  "password": "string",
  "username": "string"
}
```

My Question is how i upload `List of File's` through Swagger under `POJO class`

Comment: I'll suggest you to upload the list of files in another handler.

Comment: @akuma8 thanks for response i now that way that you answer. But i'm trying to `map multiplefile` under the `POJO`. Right now i have single object but will change into the `list of POJO`. In that case will each object have random list of File under single object.

Comment: i write the code of handle the file in spring boot diff way see my repo https://github.com/NABEEL-AHMED-JAMIL/file-uploader

Comment: Post the answer directly here

Comment: hi, @akuma8 for Swagger Image for Uploading the List File's I'm still looking but in that project, I share the possible way of handling the request of the file in spring boot. In that, I also share the angular-7 UI part.